# Parsing /proc/pid/smaps with awk

Tags: linux, memory, sed, awk, profiling

I'm looking for a short awk / sed script to extract the rss information from the proc/smaps file which has the following records format:

```
77f73000-77f74000 rw-s 00000000 fd:00 230116     /var/lib/mylib.so
Size:                 4 kB
Rss:                  4 kB
Shared_Clean:         0 kB
Shared_Dirty:         0 kB
Private_Clean:        4 kB
Private_Dirty:        0 kB
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
/var/lib/mylib.so 4
```

- extra bonus if the records can be sorted by rss size (large chunks first)

Thanks in advance,
   Avner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your selection criteria, but this only matches when an actual path is listed:

```
awk 'NF > 3 { f = $NF } $1 ~ /^Rss/ && f ~ /\// { print f, $2 }'
```

Append `sort -nr -k2,2` to do descending sort on second column.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '
    if (/^Size:\s+([0-9]+)/) {
        $h{$f} = $1
    } elsif (m{\s(/.*)$}) {
        $f = $1
    }
    }{
    print "$_\t$h{$_}\n" for sort { $h{$a} <=> $h{$b} } keys %h
    ' input.txt
```

How it works: if a line beginning with *Size* is read, remember the number at the last mentioned file. Else, if a file is mentioned, remember it. At the file end, sort the remembered pairs by the number and print them.